# Как изменить этот код так, чтоб он соответствовал ооп стандарту open cv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Как изменить этот код так, чтоб он соответствовал ооп стандарту opencv? Не могу найти нормальных примеров использования ооп стиля opencv

```
   CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
   IplImage* fr= nullptr;

   fr = cvQueryFrame( capture );
   auto temp = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", fr);
   uchar *a = temp->data.ptr;
   cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
```

Comment: @AlexF мне кажется у него предупреждение.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать 3-й или 4-й opencv, которые написаны на с++ (объектно ориентированном языке)?